# "Reasonable" requirements for a computation model to be equivalent in power to a Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, computability, computation-models

I was reading through Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" and in it, he states that all computational models with unrestricted access to unlimited memory are "equivalent in power, so long as they satisfy reasonable requirements". He gives the example of an requirement which is that only a finite amount of work is done in a step.

I was trying to think of other "reasonable" requirements but I don't know where to start. What other requirements are there for a computational model to have the same power as a Turing machine?

Comment: At the very least there should be an ability to "branch" (like `if` or `while`) and "loop" (like `while` or recursion)

Comment: One possible way to showcase these "reasonable" abilities without formally proving Turing-completeness is to implement a ["truth-machine"](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Truth-machine) in your computational model.